# At most one positive root for a sum of fractions

Tags: polynomials, roots

It seems that the following equation has at most one positive root $x \in \mathbb{R}$. How should I approach to prove it?

$\sum_{i=1}^K \frac{1}{x+id} = \sum_{i=1}^N \frac{1}{x+i}$

where $K < N$ are integers, and $d \in [0, 1]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Lemma 1:* if $f_j,g_j>0$, $f_j(x)=g_j(x)$ and $f_j(y)/f_j(x)>g_j(y)/g_j(x)$ for all $j$, then $\sum_j f_j(y)>\sum_j g_j(y)$.

*Proof:* Subtract and enjoy.

*Lemma 2:* If $y>x>0$ and $0<a<1$, then $\frac{1+ax}{1+ay}>\frac{1+x}{1+y}$

*Proof:* Same as of Lemma 1.

First, multiply by $x$, and substitute $1/x$ for $x$.
Next, let $x$ be the least positive root. Then
$a_i\frac 1{1+xid}=\frac{1}{1+xi}$ for $i\le K$ with some $a_i\in (0,1)$ while the remaining parts of the sums can also be split as $b_{ij}\frac 1{1+xid}= c_{ij}\frac 1{1+xj}$ ($i\le K, K<j\le N$). Now apply the lemmas.

Comment: Certainly not! Each identity corresponds to one part $f_k$ (the LHS) and one part $g_k$ (the RHS).

Comment: Thank you for being patient with me @fedja. I deleted the intermediate comments and updated the proof.

Comment: Looks like I'll have to take care of it too: there have been so many corrections done by other people that some parts don't look right anymore. I hope you've got it now :). If you have further questions, just ask!

Comment: I finally got it. Thank you!

Comment: I deleted all my comments that don't make independent sense without your deleted ones. :)